# qtree items do not have the same baseline

Tags: graphs, technical-drawing, qtree, baseline

I drew a tree with the `qtree` package. However, this tree has no consistent baseline.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{qtree}
\begin{document}

  \Tree[.table 
         [.thead 
           [.tr 
             [.th [.\textit{Vorname} ] ]
             [.th [.\textit{Nachname} ] ]
           ]
         ]              
         [.tbody 
           [.tr 
             [.td [.\textit{Donald} ] ]
             [.td [.\textit{Duck} ] ]
           ]
         ]
       ]

\end{document}
```

How do I get a consistent baseline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without changing anything in your tree-syntax, the [`tikz-qtree`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-qtree) package allows you to get the right result:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}

  \Tree[.table 
         [.thead 
           [.tr 
             [.th [.\textit{Vorname} ] ]
             [.th [.\textit{Nachname} ] ]
           ]
         ]              
         [.tbody 
           [.tr 
             [.td [.\textit{Donald} ] ]
             [.td [.\textit{Duck} ] ]
           ]
         ]
       ]

\end{document}
```

gives:

[image]

Comment: @BennyNeugebauer: you're welcome :)