# Drawing a tree with bottom-aligned leaves

Tags: tikz-qtree

I'd like to align all leaves of a tree at the bottom, so what I'd like to achieve should look like:

```
    p
   / \
  /  /\
 c  d  e
```

What I've tried so far (using tikz-qtree) results in:

```
    p
   / \
  c  /\
    d  e
```

I'm currently using tikz-qtree, but if there's an alternative better suited to the task, feel free to suggest one ;)
Sidenote: I'm actually not labeling nodes, but edges.

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[active,pdftex,tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\PreviewEnvironment[]{tikzpicture}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every tree node/.style={draw,circle},sibling distance=10pt,
edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode) -- (\tikzchildnode)}]
\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\tiny, sloped,anchor=south,auto=false,inner sep=1pt]
\Tree
[.{}
    \edge node[]{C};
    [.{}
    ]
    \edge node[]{A};
    [.{}
        \edge node[]{D};
        [.{}
        ]
        \edge node[]{E};
        [.{}
        ]
    ]
]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Slightly related: [qtree items do not have the same baseline](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99573/13304)

Comment: A related question: [How to draw syntactical trees with parallel leafs for a natural language?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17600)  Will this question solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a **forest** solution which allows the tree to be specified quite concisely. Once the preamble of the tree is configured (which could also be saved as a style, for example), we can write

```
  [
    [c]
    [a
      [d]
      [e]
    ]
  ]
```

to produce

[image: auto-labelling]

The alignment of the final nodes in the tree is accomplished with

```
    if n children=0{tier=terminal}{},
```

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    draw,
    circle,
    delay={
      if level=0{}{
          edge label/.wrap pgfmath arg={node [font=\tiny, sloped, midway, anchor=south, auto=false, inner sep=1pt] {#1} }{content()}
      },
    },
    if n children=0{tier=terminal}{},
    s sep=10pt,
  },
  before typesetting nodes={
    for tree={
      content=,
    }
  }
  [
    [c]
    [a
      [d]
      [e]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

This code generates what you need:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{center}
        \tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=1.5cm, sibling distance=2.5cm]
        \tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=1.5cm, sibling distance=2.5cm]
        \tikzstyle{level 3}=[level distance=1.5cm, sibling distance=1cm]
        \tikzstyle{level 4}=[level distance=1.5cm, sibling distance=2cm]
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node {p}
                child{
                    child{
                        node(a){c}
                    } child{edge from parent[draw=none] }
                }
                child{
                    node{}
                    child{
                        node(b){d}
                    }
                    child{
                        node(c){e}
                    }
                };
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Credits to [this page.](http://www.drewdimmery.com/extensive-form-game-trees-in-tikz/)